# How can we declare local variable and output its value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have declared a variable like this

```
@{ int i = 1; }
```

Now, inside `foreach` loop i want to assign the value of i each time the loop is processed;

```
 @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
 {
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@i" value="@line.Product.ProductName" />
      <input type="hidden" name="amount_@i" value="@line.Product.Price" />
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_@i" value="@line.Quantity" />
      @i++;
 }
```

but it isn't working.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need access to the index, it makes more sense to use a normal `for` loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cart.Lines.Count; i++)
{
    var line = Model.Cart.Lines[i];
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a LINQ expression:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Cart.Lines.Select((x, i) => new { Line = x, Index = i }))
{
    // Now you can access, for example, `item.Line` for the line, and 
    // `item.Index` for the index (i.e. `i`)
    ...
}
```

Comment: love ur solution and it worked. But the problem is, how to start incrementing from 1 because it is incrementing values from 0

Comment: @DigitalAssets, that depends on which solution your'e using.  For the LINQ-based approach, just change it to `Index = i + 1` instead of `Index = i`.  For the former appraoch, either declare a new variable inline, i.e.  `int j = i + 1`, or declare a second variable in your `for` statement, `for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < Model.Cart.Lines.Count; i++, j++) { ... }`.

Comment: i did this, it worked. Love your answer. I think it is the more professional way. I dont have words to thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't explained what isn't working, but from your code it appears that the value of the "i" variable isn't incrementing, instead you vet an output of "0++;".

This is because the purpose of the @ symbol in razor is

1. to output
2. identifiers, and therefore it outputs the identifier "i" and then continues with the remaining text of "++;".

To achieve what you apparently want to do (to just increment the value of i), you have to enclose it in a code block, as follows:

```
@{ i++; }
```

However if you do want to output the value of i before incrementing it, then you should wrap it in a expression block, as in the following:

```
@(i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking scope. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx

try it one code block like:

```
@{
    var i = 1;
    var tmp = "";

    foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
    {
        tmp = "item_name_" + i;
        <input type="hidden" name="@tmp" value="@line.Product.ProductName" />
        i++;
    }
}
```